# Open suse distro no display tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, opensuse

My problem is I am trying to use a module called easygui that depends upon the module `TKinter`. I am using suse studio attempting to build a personalized distro that offers a bootable advanced formatter that I would like to have a GUI with it. I have no problems with programming gui's with tkinter but I prefer to use easygui because of the simplicity. I have also tried running a tkinter script that is just a basic test. This works perfectly fine on a mac or a windows computer but when I attempt to use it with open suse I run into the problem. please note that all these files work perfectly fine with any other OS.

I have installed the `python-tk`module and I am getting an error thatstates `_tkinter.TCLError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variables` I have done my research and have not been able to find a solution to this problem. 
The modules I have installed are

1. python-tk
2. python3 (all files available)
3. python3-tk
4. ssh
5. python-tk-display
6. python-display
7. python3-display

I have tried redoing all of these packages and I still cannot seem to get it to work! The first time I tried it it did indeed work but after that I has not. Please note that I am using suse studio and I have attempted using different appliances and have infant created a new one just for figuring out this problem

Extra materials:

1. tkinter script

   ```
   import Tkinter
   import tkMessageBox

   top = Tkinter.Tk()
   def hello():
      tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", "Hello World")

   B1 = Tkinter.Button(top, text = "Say Hello", command = hello)
   B1.pack()

   top.mainloop()
   ```
2. Console error message (full)
   [image]
3. Full list of packages that I have installed 
   [image]

**UPDATE: It works when you goto terminal and attempt to use tkinter directly from terminal it works just fine but if you try running the file that has the tkinter code in it , it will not work**

Comment: you could try `export DISPLAY=:0`  ... that might work

Comment: Where would I add that? in my tkinter code?

Comment: `tux@linux->: export DISPLAY=:0` and then in the same console run the python script

Comment: why do you need to build it again? you should just run it ... meh I dunno Im no suse expert for sure

Comment: I am using a their builder which means that every time that I want to change anything I have to re-build my entire os. Also I could just do a test drive but I delete them if they don't work.

Comment: have you searched for that exact message ("no display name...")? There are questions and answers about that error. It has nothing to do with what is installed, it has everything to do with you not running in a GUI environment.

Comment: I am running a GUI enviroment! I am using Gnome 13.1